# Avoid redefinition of alias variable for weak reference in header-file

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, weak-references

I have a variable in an header file:

myHeader.h

```
uint16 dummyVar = 0;
extern const uint16 myVar __attribute__((weak,alias("dummyVar")));
```

So when I don't link the parts where `myVar` gets defined, the linker will just give it the value of the symbol `dummyVar`.

My problem is, that I am working on a Project with a given architecture, where my Header-File `myHeader.h` is included by several C-Files. Because of that I get multiple definitions of `dummyVar` . But when I define `dummyVar` outside of my header it doesnt work anymore for my `__attribute__` since `dummyVar` needs to be defined when it is assigned as an alias.

Is there any way I can work around this without changing the basic architecture of this?

Comment: The weak alias of `myVar` seems okay, however the problem is `dymmyVar` since it's defined multiple times if the header is included more than once.

Comment: Yeah well that sums up my problem pretty accurately. Since I can't define `dummyVar` outside of the header because of the `attribute`

Comment: static uint16 dummyVar = 0;

Comment: @Xonar Oh my god, sometimes I really want to punch myself - so simple and so obvious actually. Works now - Thanks you! Make it as an answer into this thread! :)

Comment: @Toby In most cases things like `uint16 dummyVar = 0;` shall not appear in a header file. Does `uint16 dummyVar __attribute__((weak));` satisfy your need? Or you may want to use `extern uint16 dummyVar;` in the header and `uint16 dummyVar = 0;` in one of the source files.

Comment: @starrify  - The problem is that it may occur that`myVar` is called even without being defined (because the according c-file is not linked) - thats why a simple `__attribute__((weak))` is not enough and I need the alias. Defining `dummyVar` in a C-File does also not work, since it needs to be defiend when I assign the `__attribute__` to `myVar`

Comment: @Xonar @Tody It is true that this generates no compilation error. However please double check whether this is what you need. This way the symbol `dummyVar` is not exported and appears locally in each source file which includes `myHeader.h`, so if you modify `dymmyVar` in one of the source files the change would be only visible in the very scope of one file.

Comment: @starrify This is totally OK for me, since I just need `dummyVar` so the program won't crash if `myVar` is called. I dont intend to change or use `dummyVar` for any specific purpose.

Comment: @Toby Okay then it's fine. Just FYI, as far as I know to use alias between compilation units the only way is to inform the linker, by either passing something like `--defsym=symbol=expression` or writing a linker script. Good luck~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to to just declare it as follows:

```
static uint16 dummyVar = 0;
```